# Christmas Gifts Employees Probability Question

Tags: probability

Our teacher assigned this problem to our class as a challenge and I was able to do some of it but got stuck. Here it is:

*A company with n employees has a scheme according to which each employee buys a Christmas gift and the gifts are then distributed at random to the employees. What is the probability that someone gets his or her own gift?*

So far, I found that the probability that an employee gets his or her own gift is $\frac 1 n$. Additionally, we can let $A_i$ equal the $ith$ employee that gets his or her own gift. This is now what we are trying to find:

$$P\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i$$

So, we have:

$$P(A_i) = \frac 1 n$$
$$P(A_i \cup A_j) = \frac{n-2!}{n!} = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$

Thus, we can deduce:

$$P(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) = \frac{1}{n!}$$

Using this, I start deducing the answer:

$$1 - \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots + (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n!}$$

After this step, I am unsure on how to proceed and simplify my work. Also, can someone tell me if I worked out the proof accurately?

Comment: This is very close to the derangement problem, which asks what the problem is that *no one* gets their own gift (or their own hat, or whatever).  The answer to both the derangement problem and your problem, in the limit as $n \to \infty$, is $1/e$, and you're almost all of the way there.  You need only the Taylor-series expansion of $e^x = 1 + x/1! + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + \cdots$, where $x = -1$ in your case.

Comment: You are working it correctly, and your answer converges to $1-\frac{1}{e}$ as $n\to\infty$ using the Taylor series for $f(x)=e^x$ with $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. The probability is approximately $$e^{-1}$$ being the first $n$ terms for the Taylor series for $e^x$ evaluated at $x=-1.$